# Game Loop, Deltas. What is wrong?

Tags: android, game-loop

For my Android app this is the gameloop:

```
public void run(){  
    while(true){
        if(frames == 0)
            cTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= lastUpdate + 5){
            if(gameState == PLAYING)
                updatePhisic();

            updateSprites();            
            this.postInvalidate();
            lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        /*try{
            Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){}*/

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= cTime + 1000){
            frameRate = frames;
            frames = 0;
        }
        else
            frames++;
    }
}
```

Please consider this should work for multiple devices.

Testing in some devices:

- My phone: 180 FPS
- A Smaller phone: 200 FPS
- A Tablet: 120 FPS

I'm trying to put it at 60 FPS but the player moves so slow, I don't know how to calculate the Delta for player. I mean that at 180 FPS in my phone works fine, that is the speed that I want. But at 120 FPS in a tablet freezes a bit.

I think that painting the screen 60 times in a second would be enough.

And this freezes sometimes:

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= lastUpdate + 5)
```

This does not:

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
}catch(InterruptedException e){}
```

Why?

Comment: I am not sure you should try to control the FPS that way. Just use a delta in the `update` methods and let the device go at its own peace

Comment: @realUser404 That's going to kill the battery in no time :P

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that stand out here. First, having 4 calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()` is at best confusing and could be the source of bugs. If `lastUpdate` is used outside of this function, it's going to represent the idle time *between* frames, not the time since the last frame. Try locking in the current time at the top of your loop instead:

```
while(true) {
    long currTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(frames == 0)
            cTime = currTimeMs;

    if(currTimeMs >= lastUpdate + 5){
        ...
        lastUpdate = currTimeMs;
    }


    if(currTimeMs >= cTime + 1000){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Along the same lines, you should have a fixed delta and pass that around:

```
if(currTimeMs >= lastUpdate + 5){
    deltaMs = currTimeMs - lastUpdate;
    ...
    // Make use of deltaMs
    ...
    lastUpdate = currTimeMs;
}
```

This gives the rest of the code a consistent view of time.

Second, you're not counting your frame rate correctly, so the numbers you mentioned are likely misleading. `frames++` happens outside your update block, meaning that you increment the frame count even if you didn't render a frame.